# Error while installing logging package on Anaconda Prompt

Tags: logging, pip, installation

I get the following error while trying to install 'logging' package on anaconda prompt. Can you please help me sort this issue ?

Collecting logging
  Using cached logging-0.4.9.6.tar.gz (96 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\15084\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\15084\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i4yxk7tl\logging\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\15084\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i4yxk7tl\logging\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\15084\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i4yxk7tl\logging\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\15084\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i4yxk7tl\logging\
    Complete output (48 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating C:\Users\15084\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i4yxk7tl\logging\pip-egg-info\logging.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\15084\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i4yxk7tl\logging\pip-egg-info\logging.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\15084\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i4yxk7tl\logging\pip-egg-info\logging.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\15084\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i4yxk7tl\logging\pip-egg-info\logging.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\15084\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i4yxk7tl\logging\pip-egg-info\logging.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "C:\Users\15084\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i4yxk7tl\logging\setup.py", line 13, in 
        packages = ["logging"],
      File "c:\users\15084\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\15084\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\15084\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\15084\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 296, in run
        self.find_sources()
      File "c:\users\15084\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 303, in find_sources
        mm.run()
      File "c:\users\15084\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 534, in run
        self.add_defaults()
      File "c:\users\15084\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 570, in add_defaults
        sdist.add_defaults(self)
      File "c:\users\15084\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\sdist.py", line 226, in add_defaults
        self._add_defaults_python()
      File "c:\users\15084\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\sdist.py", line 127, in _add_defaults_python
        build_py = self.get_finalized_command('build_py')
      File "c:\users\15084\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 298, in get_finalized_command
        cmd_obj = self.distribution.get_command_obj(command, create)
      File "c:\users\15084\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 857, in get_command_obj
        klass = self.get_command_class(command)
      File "c:\users\15084\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 841, in get_command_class
        self.cmdclass[command] = cmdclass = ep.load()
      File "c:\users\15084\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 2443, in load
        return self.resolve()
      File "c:\users\15084\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 2449, in resolve
        module = **import**(self.module_name, fromlist=['**name**'], level=0)
      File "c:\users\15084\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py", line 15, in 
        from setuptools.lib2to3_ex import Mixin2to3
      File "c:\users\15084\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\lib2to3_ex.py", line 12, in 
        from lib2to3.refactor import RefactoringTool, get_fixers_from_package
      File "c:\users\15084\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\lib2to3\refactor.py", line 18, in 
        import logging
      File "C:\Users\15084\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i4yxk7tl\logging\logging__init__.py", line 618
        raise NotImplementedError, 'emit must be implemented '\
                                 ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`logging` is a [package from the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html), you must not install it with `pip`, you get it for free when installing Python.

The one that you're trying to install with `pip install logging` is a [very old release](https://pypi.org/project/logging/) intended for old versions of Python 2.